# When keeping a client socket open to send several messages, why does the program give an error when there is a big delay in messages?

Tags: python, sockets

There is a server that listens to connections. The client socket connects to the server and calls `sendall()` several times in a loop before closing it. However, if any iteration takes a while, there is a `ConnectionAbortedError`.

There is a loop going from 0-9, where in every iteration, there is a `sendall()` using the client socket. To create a delay, I added a dummy while loop which just increments some variable.

The relevant part of the server code

```
with socket.socket() as s:
    s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 65432))
    s.listen()

    while True:
        connection, address = s.accept()

        with connection:
            data = connection.recv(72)
            print('Client says "{}"'.format(data))
```

The client code

```
with socket.socket() as s:
    s.connect((host, port))
    for i in range(10):
        s.sendall(bytes("message {}".format(i+1), encoding='utf-8'))

        if i+1 == 3:
            count = 0
            while count < 12000:
                count += 1
```

A small limit to count in the `while` loop like 500 works fine. However, something above 5000 seems to cause an error. It is not clear to me why they give different results.

Comment: "cause an error" -- please be more specific, see [ask]. Also, "relevant part of [...] code" may or may not be true, it's better to provide a [mcve]. Actually, it's even required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server reads exactly once from the client and receives up to 72 bytes then closes the connection.  If the client can send all 10 messages fast enough it won't get an error.  Read about the [Nagle Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) which:

> inhibit[s] the sending of new TCP segments when new outgoing data arrives from the user if any previously transmitted data on the connection remains unacknowledged.

Your server will never receive all the messages (total 91 bytes) but the client won't error if it gets them all sent.

A small change to the server makes sure it receives all the data (no matter the delay) by waiting until the client closes the connection:

```
with connection:
    while True:
        data = connection.recv(72)
        if not data: break # empty data means client closed connection.
        print('Client says "{}"'.format(data))
```

This still won't receive messages one-by-one.  TCP is a streaming protocol so the messages get concatenated together.  You need to add buffering and a means to extract only complete messages from it.  Example (Python 3.6+):

**client.py**

```
import socket

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 65432

with socket.socket() as s:
    s.connect((host, port))
    for i in range(10):
        # Use newline as message delimiter.
        s.sendall(f'message {i+1}\n'.encode())
```

**server.py**

```
import socket

with socket.socket() as s:
    s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 65432))
    s.listen()

    while True:
        connection, address = s.accept()

        with connection:
            data = b''
            while True:
                chunk = connection.recv(16)
                if not chunk: break # client closed connection
                data += chunk # buffer input
                while b'\n' in data: # break off messages and display
                    msg,_,data = data.partition(b'\n')
                    print(f'Client says "{msg.decode()}"')
            if data:
                print(f'Incomplete message: {data}')
```

Output:

```
Client says "message 1"
Client says "message 2"
Client says "message 3"
Client says "message 4"
Client says "message 5"
Client says "message 6"
Client says "message 7"
Client says "message 8"
Client says "message 9"
Client says "message 10"
```

Answer (score 3):

Your server code is incorrect. You should use `threading` or any other technique to serve multiple client connections. What is happening here:

1) Server accepts first socket

2) Server receives 72 bytes

3) Connection **is closed** because `with` operator closes it

4) Server goes to next `accept`-loop