# Keep socket open until client terminates

Tags: python, sockets

I am passing a user input license key (client) to a validation (server) that maps the user input to the valid licenses in my licensing API. I need the server connection to stay open until the client sends the correct license - maybe close the connection after 3 attempts. When I open the server socket it closes upon receiving the first input from the client - whether it is a good request or bad. How do I close the connection only on successful validation?

I tried wrapping the validation check in a loop but this becomes recursive as we need the user to initiate the validation check when they click submit from tkinter button on client.

```
import requests
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import socket

key = '***'
secret = '***'
request_type = {'Content-type': 'text/xml', 'Accept': 'text/xml'}
productURL = 'https://'+key+':'+secret+'@www.sendowl.com/api/v1/products'
orderURL = 'https://'+key+':'+secret+'@www.sendowl.com/api/v1_3/orders'

order_id = []
lic_key = []

def Main():
    data = ""
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 5000

    mySocket = socket.socket()
    mySocket.bind((host,port))

    mySocket.listen(5)
    conn, addr = mySocket.accept()
    print ("Connection from: " + str(addr))
    user_key = conn.recv(1024).decode()            

    order_response = requests.get(orderURL, headers=request_type)

    order_root = ET.fromstring(order_response.content)

    for child in order_root.iter('*'):
        if child.tag == 'id':
            order_id.append(child.text)

    i = 0
    while i < len(order_id):
        licenseURL = 'https://'+key+':'+secret+'@www.sendowl.com/api/v1/orders/'+order_id[i]+'/licenses'
        lic_response = requests.get(licenseURL, headers=request_type)
        lic_root = ET.fromstring(lic_response.content)

        for child in lic_root.iter('*'):
            if child.tag == 'key':
                lic_key.append(child.text)
        i += 1

    print("validating...........")
    if data != "SUCCESS":
        if user_key in lic_key:
            message = "Success"
        else:
            message = "Failure"    
        data = str(message).upper()
        print ("sending: " + str(data))
        conn.send(data.encode())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: Read how to create a [mcve].  Your server in this example never closes the connection directly, but only reads one blob and sends one blob.  When `Main()` returns, `mySocket` is out of scope closing the connection.  Note that TCP is a streaming protocol, so `recv(1024)` can receive any amount of data from 0 (client closed connection) to 1024 bytes of data.  You'll need to define a protocol and ensure you read until you have a complete message, and send complete messages.  After accepting the connection, loop on receiving messages and sending good/bad responses until you have a good message.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53962492/235698) I recently gave has an example of a message protocol.