# Python breaks string after first character

Tags: python, python-3.5, serversocket

My Python socket program is breaking after the first character when receiving a single line string. The socket program runs in Raspberry Pi and the client and Java. Here is my code for socket

```
HOST = ''
PORT = 8888

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print('Socket created')

try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as socketError:
    print('socket binding failed, ', socketError)
    print('Exiting...')
    sys.exit(0)

print('Socket binding complete')

s.listen(1)
print('Socket listening for connection...')

conn, addr = s.accept()

print('connected to ',addr[0])

try:
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        print('value received',data)

except Exception as loopException:
    print("Exception occurred in loop, exiting...",loopException)
finally:
    s.close()
```

This is how I send data from java

```
socket = new Socket(dstAddress, Integer.parseInt(dstPort));
os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes("Connection-Ready to receive commands");
```

This is what I get in terminal

```
value received C
value received onnected-Ready to receive commands
```

Does anybody know why it is behaving like this?

Comment: Have you tried adding a short `sleep` before the first `recv`?

Comment: No, let me try it

Comment: Adding a sleep might appear to work, but is the wrong solution.  Design a protocol to determine you have all the bytes. It is completely legal for `recv(1024)` to return only one byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read in a loop until you get all of the input.  You need a way to know when you have all of the input.

If the client is writing and then closing the socket, then you can read until you get to EOF.  If the client isn't closing the socket, then you need some way to know how much to read.  The simplest thing is to have the client send a length word before sending the characters.  You read the length and then read that many characters.

To put in a delay is a hack that may work for now, but isn't reliable.  If you have some slowdown in your network, your code can break.

It looks from your output like you are closing the stream on the client side even though you don't show that.  So then you just need to buffer up all your data until you reach the end of the stream.  This should work:

```
buffer = b''
try:
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        buffer += data
except Exception as loopException:
    print("Exception occurred in loop, exiting...", loopException)
finally:
    s.close()

print('value received', buffer.decode('utf-8'))
```

I think this will work.  I don't have a connection to try it against, but my IDE likes it.  I'm not that familiar with Python 3 byte streams. If this doesn't quite work, you should get the idea here anyway.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example.  I added a check that I think will work so that you won't have to have an exception thrown to exit your loop.

Comment: I updated my answer again to show how to capture the bytes, and decode at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Sockets are a byte stream and there is no guarantee that a `recv` will have all the bytes of a complete message. It is your responsibility to buffer the received data until you have a complete message.

This also means you need to provide a way to know you have a complete message. Send the length of the message before the message, or read until a newline.

Comment: @Sony This is a common question on SO. 
 Here's one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53962492/235698.